# How to convert *.urdf.xacro files to *.sdf for gazebo?

Tags: ros, gazebo, urdf, sdf, xacro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear all,

as with the latest gazebo version (1.7.12-s1367893033~precise) in groovy, it seems that our *.urdf.xacro files are finally not supported anymore.

I found out about the latest .sdf format (1.3) and already tried to update some of our files. I.e. I replaced

```
  <xacro:macro name="sick_s300_laser_gazebo_v0" params="name ros_topic update_rate min_angle max_angle">
    <gazebo reference="${name}_link">
      <sensor:ray name="${name}">
        <rayCount>541</rayCount>
        <rangeCount>541</rangeCount>
        <laserCount>1</laserCount>

        <origin>0.0 0.0 0.0</origin>
        <displayRays>false</displayRays>

        <minAngle>${min_angle*180.0/M_PI}</minAngle>
        <maxAngle>${max_angle*180.0/M_PI}</maxAngle>

        <minRange>0.05</minRange>
        <maxRange>30.0</maxRange>
        <resRange>0.03</resRange>
        <updateRate>${update_rate}</updateRate>
        <controller:gazebo_ros_laser name="gazebo_ros_${name}_controller" plugin="libgazebo_ros_laser.so">
          <gaussianNoise>0.005</gaussianNoise>
          <alwaysOn>true</alwaysOn>
          <updateRate>${update_rate}</updateRate>
          <topicName>${ros_topic}</topicName>
          <frameName>/${name}_link</frameName>
          <interface:laser name="gazebo_ros_${name}_iface" />
        </controller:gazebo_ros_laser>
      </sensor:ray>
      <material value="IPA/LightGrey" />
    </gazebo>
  </xacro:macro>
```

with

```
  <xacro:macro name="sick_s300_laser_gazebo_v0" params="name ros_topic update_rate min_angle max_angle">
    <gazebo reference="${name}_link">
    <sensor name="${name}" type="ray">
        <ray>
            <scan>
                <horizontal>
                    <samples>541</samples>
                    <resolution>1.0</resolution>
                    <min_angle>${min_angle*180.0/M_PI}</min_angle>
                    <max_angle>${max_angle*180.0/M_PI}</max_angle>
                </horizontal>
            </scan>
            <range>
                <min>0.05</min>
                <max>30.0</max>
                <resolution>0.03</resolution>
            </range>
        </ray>
    </sensor>       

      <material value="IPA/LightGrey" />
    </gazebo>
  </xacro:macro>
```

for the urdf.xacro files for one of our sensors.

However, if I then spawn our robot, I get the following message from gazebo:

```
fxm@sony-fxm:/opt/ros/groovy/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo_worlds/worlds$ roslaunch gazebo_worlds empty_world.launch 
... logging to /home/fxm/.ros/log/320cbf70-bca0-11e2-9ff7-00271039ca78/roslaunch-sony-fxm-20823.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://sony-fxm:55478/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /rosdistro
 * /rosversion
 * /use_sim_time

NODES
  /
    gazebo (gazebo/gazebo)
    gazebo_gui (gazebo/gui)

auto-starting new master
process[master]: started with pid [20837]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

setting /run_id to 320cbf70-bca0-11e2-9ff7-00271039ca78
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [20850]
started core service [/rosout]
process[gazebo-2]: started with pid [20864]
process[gazebo_gui-3]: started with pid [20876]
Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 1.5.0
Copyright (C) 2013 Open Source Robotics Foundation.
Released under the Apache 2 License.
http://gazebosim.org

Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 1.5.0
Copyright (C) 2013 Open Source Robotics Foundation.
Released under the Apache 2 License.
http://gazebosim.org

Warning [parser.cc:361] Converting a deprecated SDF source[/opt/ros/groovy/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo_worlds/worlds/empty.world].
Set SDF value
  Version[1.2] to Version[1.3]
  Please use the gzsdf tool to update your SDF files.
    $ gzsdf convert [sdf_file]
Msg Waiting for master[ INFO] [1368540701.989137839]: waitForService: Service [/gazebo/set_physics_properties] has not been advertised, waiting...

Msg Connected to gazebo master @ http://127.0.0.1:11345
Msg Publicized address: 10.17.55.151
Msg Waiting for master
Msg Connected to gazebo master @ http://127.0.0.1:11345
Msg Publicized address: 10.17.55.151
Error [Events.hh:141] Events::ConnectWorldUpdateStart is deprecated in v 1.5.0. Please use Events::ConnectWorldUpdateBegin
Error [Events.hh:141] Events::ConnectWorldUpdateStart is deprecated in v 1.5.0. Please use Events::ConnectWorldUpdateBegin
Error [Events.hh:141] Events::ConnectWorldUpdateStart is deprecated in v 1.5.0. Please use Events::ConnectWorldUpdateBegin
[ INFO] [1368540703.812490419]: joint trajectory plugin missing <updateRate>, defaults to 0.0 (as fast as possible)
Error [Events.hh:141] Events::ConnectWorldUpdateStart is deprecated in v 1.5.0. Please use Events::ConnectWorldUpdateBegin
[ INFO] [1368540703.842767312, 0.023000000]: waitForService: Service [/gazebo/set_physics_properties] is now available.
[ INFO] [1368540703.883032363, 0.057000000]: Starting to spin physics dynamic reconfigure node...
Warning [parser.cc:377] SDF has no <sdf> element in file[data-string]
Dbg extension [<sensor name="base_laser_front" type="ray"><ray><scan><horizontal><samples>541</samples><resolution>1.0</resolution><min_angle>-135.000315689</min_angle><max_angle>135.000315689</max_angle></horizontal></scan><range><min>0.05</min><max>30.0</max><resolution>0.03</resolution></range></ray></sensor>] not converted.
Dbg extension [<sensor name="base_laser_rear" type="ray"><ray><scan><horizontal><samples>541</samples><resolution>1.0</resolution><min_angle>-135.000315689</min_angle><max_angle>135.000315689</max_angle></horizontal></scan><range><min>0.05</min><max>30.0</max><resolution>0.03</resolution></range></ray></sensor>] not converted.
Dbg [base_footprint] has no parent joint
Warning [parser.cc:314] parse from urdf.
```

The robot spawns within gazebo but there no sensor message is published.
It is similar for our controllers. They don't work anymore as well.

My questions now are:

- Why are the gazebo extensions not converted? Is there something wrong?
- What is best practise to convert .urdf.xacro files into the new .sdf format?
- Where can I find examples? Has the PR2 been updated yet?

With best regards,

Felix

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/62697/how-to-convert-*.urdf.xacro-files-to-*.sdf-for-gazebo?/) by [Felix Messmer](https://answers.ros.org/users/208/felix-messmer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 198 on 2013-05-14

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Gazer](https://answers.ros.org/users/4846/gazer/) on 2013-05-14**:
hello, did u figure it out? I also have the same problem. I am interested in opening up .xacro.urdf file using gazebo 1.7. Did you successfully open it up?

**Comment by [Felix Messmer](https://answers.ros.org/users/208/felix-messmer/) on 2013-05-14**:
Hi,
I was able to load a robot modeled as urdf.xacro.
However, it's rather only the meshes and kinematic chain - as the problem is that the sensors and controllers from the urdf.xacro are not working anymore, i.e. the robot cannot "see" and cannot "move"....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Looks like you already asked on [answers.gazebosim.org](http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/2906/how-to-convert-urdfxacro-files-to-sdf-for-gazebo/) and got an answer there.
Also, these days there's a [Tutorial: Using a URDF in Gazebo](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials/?tut=ros_urdf).

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2015-07-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0